# Open a xls file with SAX approach in .Net and adding several rows (about 100K)

Tags: c#, sax, xls

I need your support.
I need to open a .xls file with c# adding about 100k of rows.
I tried several approach, but all approaches run me into memory error, except for OpenXML with SAX Approach. This one works for me.
My problem is I'm able to create excel with 100K rows from the scratch (and it works like a charm), but I'm not able to open a file xls that for example has first row with titles, second row with formulas, and suppose I've to add 100K rows from the third row of this excel.
This is my code.
When i run it, file is cloned but no rows are added...could you please help me?
Thanks

```
//copy of file
String str_IntermidiateXLSPath = "c:\\testXls3.xlsx";
File.Copy("c:\\testXls.xlsx", str_IntermidiateXLSPath, true);
using (SpreadsheetDocument SpreadsheetDocumentObj = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(str_IntermidiateXLSPath, true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = null;
    WorksheetPart worksheetpart = null;
    OpenXmlWriter writer = null;
    Cell cell = null;
    Row row = null;

    SpreadsheetDocumentObj.CompressionOption = CompressionOption.SuperFast;
    workbookpart = SpreadsheetDocumentObj.WorkbookPart;
    worksheetpart = workbookpart.WorksheetParts.First();

    writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(worksheetpart);
    writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());
    writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());
    //starting row
    for (int i = 3; i < 80; i++)
    {
        row = new Row();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            cell = new Cell();
            row.Append(cell);

            cell.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
            cell.InlineString = new InlineString { Text = new Text { Text = "XXX" } };
        }

        writer.WriteElement(row);
    }

    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.Close();
    workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
    SpreadsheetDocumentObj.Close();
}
Process.Start(str_IntermidiateXLSPath);
```